# What's the MSVC equivalent for -fno-char8_t?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, c++20, char8-t

In C++20 `u8` string literals are based on the `char8_t` type. They deliberately do not convert to `char const*` any more:

```
const char* str = u8"Hall\u00f6chen \u2603"; // no longer valid in C++20
```

Of course, the ultimate goal when migrating to C++20 is to entirely go with the new behaviour (in the example above: change the type of `str`). However, because of 3rd party libraries, this is often not possible immediately.

The proposals that [introduce](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0482r6.html) and ["remedy"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1423r3.html) `char8_t` anticipate that and mention that in clang and gcc there is the `-fno-char8_t` flag to switch back to the old behaviour (while still being able to enjoy other C++20 features).

The 2nd proposal sets up the expectation that Microsoft will follow and add a similar flag, but I was not able to find how to set it (at least in VS 2019, Version 16.4).

So does anyone know what the MSVC equivalent for `-fno-char8_t` is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since 16.1, there is the conformance compiler flag [`/Zc:char8_t-`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/cpp-conformance-improvements?view=vs-2019#char8_t). The minus tells the compiler to *not* use conformance mode here when using C++20. On the contrary, `/Zc:char8_t` can be used to enable it.

Comment: Oh, good spot. I was about to write an answer saying there isn't one :)

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica thanks for adding the reference!

Comment: Thought I ought to contribute _something_ :P

Comment: Improved it a bit, too, since it is something I wanted to know; so I ought to contribute too :P